# Enabling Local Plugins in Ckeditor using CDN

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, text-editor

I m try to enabling local plugins like Youtube

The editor works fine, no javascript errors, but dont show the youtube icon in the toolbar.

so far my code look like this

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.2/full-all/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script>

  CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal( 'youtube', '/appx/ipage/ckeditor/plugins/youtube/', 'plugin.js' );
  CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor-full', {


        toolbar: [
            { name: 'others', items: [ 'Youtube' ] },
            { name: 'document', items: [ 'Print','Source' ] },
            { name: 'clipboard', items: [ 'Undo', 'Redo'] },
            { name: 'styles', items: [ 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize' ] },
            { name: 'basicstyles', items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'RemoveFormat', 'CopyFormatting' ] },
            { name: 'colors', items: [ 'TextColor', 'BGColor' ] },
            { name: 'align', items: [ 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock' ] },
            { name: 'links', items: [ 'Link', 'Unlink' ] },
            { name: 'paragraph', items: [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote' ] },
            { name: 'insert', items: [ 'Image', 'Table'] },
            { name: 'clipboard', items: ['Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord'] }           
        ],

        customConfig: '',
        disallowedContent: 'img{width,height,float}',
        extraAllowedContent: 'img[width,height,align]',
        // Enabling extra plugins, available in the full-all preset: http://ckeditor.com/presets-all
        extraPlugins: 'tableresize,uploadimage,uploadfile,embed,autoembed',
        height:600,
        contentsCss: [ 'https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.2/full-all/contents.css', '/appx/ipage/ckeditor/editors/article-editor/mystyles.css' ],

        // This is optional, but will let us define multiple different styles for multiple editors using the same CSS file.
        bodyClass: 'document-editor'
</script>
```

I have try load the ckeditor.js local but then i get a icon error.

Any ideias?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Step 1.

```
config.extraPlugins = 'youtube';
```

Step 2 Add Icons to toolbar:

```
config.toolbar = [{ name: 'insert', items: ['Image', 'Youtube']}];
```

Step 3: Configuration

```
config.youtube_width = '640';

config.youtube_height = '480';

config.youtube_related = true;

config.youtube_older = false;
```